# datetime offset issue while saving data into parquet for day light saving time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, dst

[screenshot from source and destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGfX4.jpg)While we are writing into parquet file using spark/scala, DST(day light saving times) times are auto converting by one hour delay time for example (2011-09-20 00:00:00.000 into "2011-09-19 23:00:00.000").

Source(reading data from) : sql server
Destination(writing into ):  AWS S3

code:

```
val ssdf= spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver" , "${ssDriver}").
option("url", "${ssConnectionString}").
option("dbtable", "${SCHEMANAME}.${RESULTTABLENAME}").
option("user", "${ssUsername}").
option("password", "${ssPassword}").
load()


ssdf.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").save("s3://targetS3path/")`
```

###########################################################

Code is running fine, but which dates are DST datetime, delaying by 1 hour. check screenshot.

Expecting datetime value as per source, 2011-09-20 00:00:00.000.

Answer (score 0):

Set the JVM timezone you will need to add extra JVM options for the driver and executors:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
      .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=GMT")
      .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=GMT")
      .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
      .getOrCreate();
```